# Insert eps graphics with graphicx (file not found)

Tags: graphics, pdftex, miktex, eps, epstopdf

When I run [Andrew Robert's `import.tex`](http://www.andy-roberts.net/writing/latex/importing_images) in MikTeX I get an error message saying that the image file is not found:

```
! LaTeX Error: File `chick' not found.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.21   \includegraphics{chick}

?
```

I have put the image file (in this case `chick.eps`) in the same folder as `import.tex`.

Comment: You are probably use `pdflatex` instead of `latex`. The former is actually recommended but doesn't support EPS graphics but only JPG, PNG and PDF.

Comment: Also, it appears that the file downloaded form the web site is called `chick1`, or `chick2`, etc and not `chick` so check the name.  I got the error after downloading the file and hence noticed the different name then the file is importing.

Comment: Thanks Martin. The problem was indeed that I am using pdflatex (that's default in miktex's texworks). I followed the instructions [here](http://kile.sourceforge.net/Documentation/html/build_epsgraphics.html) to convert the eps to a pdf during the compilation.

Comment: Also, the `pdflatex` in TeX Live 2010 and 2011 can automatically convert EPS graphics to their PDF equivalent.

Comment: @MikeRenfro: But only with `-shell-escape` activated?

Comment: @MartinScharrer: No. TeX Live has a list of save programm calls. So the default `shell_escape = p` at texmf.cnf together with `repstopdf` (the restricted/save variant of `epstopdf`) at the `shell_escape_commands` (that is default too) is enough.

Comment: @Schweinebacke: Thanks, now I remember that.

Comment: @Sverre I think we need to see your log file to establish, for example, what version of the various support packages you are using.

Comment: If this is solved, could you post the solution in the form of an answer and mark it so? :)

Comment: @MartinScharrer: Since your comment solved the problem, I think you should post this as an answer, and perhaps elude to @ Schweinebacke's addition of TeX Live's auto-conversion capability. I don't know anything about it, since I use the appropriate graphics for the compiler anyway.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You are probably use `pdflatex` instead of `latex`. The former is actually recommended but doesn't support EPS graphics but only JPG, PNG and PDF.
You should convert the EPS to PDF using e.g. `epstopdf`. Newer versions of `pdflatex` from TeX Live should do this conversion automatically by running a restricted version (for safety reasons) called `repstopdf`.

Comment: You should never use `convert` to convert EPS to PDF. First of all, this would convert the EPS to a bitmap (embedded to a PDF). In case of JPGs embedded to EPS, they would be decompressed and the PDF would become very large. So please use [repstopdf](http://ctan.org/pkg/epstopdf) to convert EPS into PDF. This is, what TeX Live since 2010 would do on-the-fly and out of the box, if the defaults `shell_escpape = p` and the entry `repstopdf` for variable `shell_escape_commands` at the default texmf.cnf are not changed.

Comment: @Schweinebacke: Sorry, too early in the morning. I didn't had a coffee yet. I meant `epstopdf` but wrote `convert`. I use the latter very often for all raster images.

Comment: Don't be angry but I've written a more detailed answer …

Comment: In fact, I suspect it's the lack of bounding box information in the pdf which causes pdflatex to complain that the file is missing even if it is actually there.

Comment: @AndreHolzner: No, if you write `\includegraphics{chick}` then the file is searched with all supported file extensions. Now, `pdflatex` is not supporting EPS files, so doesn't find `chick.eps`. If there would be a `chick.pdf` in the same directory it would use that one.

Answer (score 8):

Using **MiKTeX** you have to use the recommended graphics format depending on the engine you are using.

So, if you are using **latex**—mostly at a queue latex→dvips→pstopdf—you can only use **EPS**, PCX, BMP, MSP, PICT or PNTG, all of them with different file extensions and sometimes with additional endings. EPS is the most recommended file format with latex→dvips, because the dimensions of EPS may be detected by `graphics/graphicx` itself. For the other file formats you need additional bb-files with the dimensions or to use option `boundingbox`.

If you are using **pdflatex** with direct PDF output, you can only use PDF, JPEG, PNG and MPS. (Note: MPS is a subtype of EPS generated by `MetaPost` and needs parts of `ConTeXt` to be installed.)

With **TeX Live** since 2010, support for on-the-fly conversion of EPS to PDF has been added. This should be activated out if the box. The conversion consists in three parts:

1. A `graphics.cfg` file, that supports file extensions `.ps` and `.eps` even, if pdflatex with direct pdf output is used.
2. LaTeX package [epstopdf](http://ctan.org/pkg/epstopdf-pkg), that uses shell escapes to convert eps to pdf on the fly using [repstopdf](http://ctan.org/pkg/epstopdf).
3. A `texmf.cnf` with settings `shell_escpape = p` and `shell_escape_commands = repstopdf`.

Because of this, you may use EPS with pdflatex and direct PDF output, if you are using TeX Live since 2010.

With **MiKTeX** you may use on-the-fly conversion, too. In this case you have to load LaTeX package `epstopdf` on your own (see the manual for more information) and you have to set command line option `--enable-write18` at call of `pdflatex`. If you call `pdflatex` from within a LaTeX editor, have a look at the editor or the profile settings and the editor manual to find out, where you may add this command line option.

You may test the on-the-fly conversion using:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.eps}
%!
%%BoundingBox:100 100 172 172
100 100 moveto
72 72 rlineto
72 neg 0 rlineto
72 72 neg rlineto
stroke
100 100 moveto
/Times-Roman findfont
72 scalefont
setfont
(A) show
showpage
\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{ifpdf}

\begin{document}
\ifpdf
  You are using pdf\LaTeX. If you see the picture, on-the-fly conversion does work!
\else
  You need to use pdflatex to test the on-the-fly conversion! You may see the
  original eps file without conversion now:
\fi

\includegraphics{\jobname.eps}
\end{document}
```

Instead of using on-the-fly conversion you may simply convert every EPS to PDF using [epstopdf](http://ctan.org/pkg/epstopdf). In this case you may remove extra white space around the picture using [pdfcrop](http://ctan.org/pkg/pdfcrop).

Note, that sometimes the conversion to PDF results in PDFs with bad Bounding Box. In this case, you should search for `%%PageBoundingBox` at the PS file and copy the four dimensions at this line to the line `%%BoundingBox` at the begin or end of the file (replacing the values you'd find there). On-the-fly conversion will be use these new values at next run of pdflatex. If you are using manual conversion, don't forget to do it again.

To convert PDF to EPS the usage of `pdftops --eps` is recommended. This is a command line utility from [xpdf](http://foolabs.com/xpdf). Note, that this is available not only for Linux, but for Windows too. Alternative you may use `pdf2ps`, a [ghostscript](http://www.ghostscript.com) command line utility. But the results may be not a good as the results of `pdftops`.

Comment: I miss the `epstopdf` loading. Let me point to [Including pdf figures in Latex document using TexnicCenter](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/52026).

Comment: Thanks. Nice and detailed answer. Most importantly you provide simple solution to everyone. For instance, I didn't have to install TeX Live instead of MiKTeX and just added `\usepackage{esptopdf}`. This is especially important for the folks who are writing a paper close to the deadline and just need a quick solution.

Answer (score 1):

I had problem not being able to read the eps file using TeXworks.
I fixed the problem by including the following line in the tex file:

```
\usepackage{epstopdf}
```

I then called the file using:

```
\includegraphics[scale=0.9]{SecularGmst.eps}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Yepp, but one must take care that `epstopdf` is loaded _after_ `graphics`/`graphicx`. In TeX Live this is not needed. See also my comment to [Schweinebacke’s answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/35261/9237).

Comment: A suggestion: Do us a favour and change your username to something more telling than "user1234".

Answer (score 0):

For what its worth, I tried all the above methods and none worked. Eventually, I found that TeXstudio was calling `repstopdf` and not `epstopdf`. `repstopdf` was symlinked to `epstopdf` under `/usr/texbin`. I removed the `repstopdf` symlink and recreated it to point to the same file that `epstopdf` was symlinked to after which it worked.

```
cd /usr/texbin
rm repstopdf
ln -s ../../texmf-dist/scripts/epstopdf/epstopdf.pl repstopdf
```

I am running TeXstudio v2.6.6 on Mountain Lion/Mac.

Comment: I'm also having the same problem with TeXstudio (v2.7.0 on OSX Mavericks 10.9.2). I tried it in Latexian and there was no problem, so it's definitely a TeXstudio issue. Your solution didn't work for me, unfortunately...

Comment: Ok, problem solved within TeXstudio's preferences. It has its own internal `$PATH` variable, which was set to an old (and no longer installed) TeXLive. Changing this to the current version fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The filecontents first line should be "%!PS" instead of "%!"
to avoid "Invalid binary DOS header" from epstopdf.cpp available at
ftp://163.143.1.21/pub/tex/miktex-svn/miktex-latest/Programs/MiKTeX/epstopdf/epstopdf.cpp

My setup is
C:\Pub\Tex>pdflatex -version

MiKTeX-pdfTeX 2.9.4225 (1.40.12) (MiKTeX 2.9)

J. Gélinas

Comment: This does not answer the question. Instead, it appears as if you are providing the answer to another problem you are having. If so, please open a new question about your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Change pdflatex to xelatex, it solves the problem for me.