# Can't use .eps instead of .jpg or .png

Tags: graphics, pdftex, eps

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Insert eps graphics with graphicx (file not found)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33896/insert-eps-graphics-with-graphicx-file-not-found)

I'm trying to follow the tutorial on this website ([link](http://www.matthewjmiller.net/howtos/customized-cover-letter-scripts/)).

I can typeset the cover letter example with a `.jpg`, but not a `.eps`. I get the error

```
! LaTeX Error: File `figures/UILogoLG3L' not found.
See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type H for immediate help.
...
l.14 } % ?
```

Comment: You have to compile with `latex` not with `pdflatex` as it is a eps figure. If you want to use eps figure and compile with `pdflatex`, you may need to load the package `epstopdf`.

Comment: Try to add the extension `figures/UILogoLG3L.eps` and, as @HarishKumar suggested, load the package `\usepackage{epstopdf}`.

Comment: I agree with Harish Kumar but thought [this link](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Importing_Graphics) might give you more of an explanation.

Comment: I can't compile with latex, I don't have that option. I have pdfLatex and a bunch of other ones, but not latex. How do I get latex? Also, How do I "load a package"?

Comment: Your editor should be able to do it. Or from command line execute `latex -shell-escape yourfile.tex` (since `epstopdf` needs `shell escape`). To load a package, simply put `\usepackage{epstopdf}` in your preamble (between `\documentclass{article}` and `\begin{document}`)

Answer (score 0):

Convert the `eps` to `jpg` using `eps2pdf` utility or another converter (such as Adobe Acrobat Professional. Then you can include it (since `pdflatex` does not recognize `.eps` files)