# texworks on mac epstopdf or repstopdf not found

Tags: mac, texworks, epstopdf

I am running texworks on mac and pdflatex to generate pdf.

epstopdf used to run fine until i upgraded my mac to the new yosemite.

Now I have this problem -

```
[1{/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}]sh: repstopdf: command not found
```

I tried to manually add

```
--enable-write18 

[1{/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}]sh: epstopdf: command not found
```

I also installed texlive-fontutils through macports

Could anyone tell me how to solve this. I added `\usepackage{epstopdf}` to the preamble.

I can access both `repstopdf` and `epstopdf` on my terminal

I tried various solutions posted here [tex-soln](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33896/insert-eps-graphics-with-graphicx-file-not-found)

**UPDATE:**

Taking the suggestion I installed texlive 2014 and removed the 2011 version:

I have the same problem:

```
[1{/opt/local/var/db/texmf/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}]sh: repstopdf: command not found
```

Comment: You might be best to reinstall the main TeXlive tree - the Yosemite upgrade copies everything in `/usr/local` apparently one file at a time, so possibly it has broken something in your set up.  But I also notice that you are using TexLive 2011, so perhaps it's time for an upgrade to TexLive 2014? The best way to do that is to install the MacTeX package - 2G bytes, but worth it.

Comment: could i install texlive from macports ?

Comment: i installed texlive and i still have the same problem   
[1{/opt/local/var/db/texmf/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}]sh: repstopdf: command not found

Comment: Depending on how it's invoked, you could be running into an environment variable bug in Yosemite that breaks subprocess launching under some conditions. If `repstopdf` is not invoked with a full path, and/or the `PATH` environment variable isn't explicitly set in TeXworks, that's likely the source of your problems. More info here: https://code.google.com/p/mactlmgr/issues/detail?id=102 if anyone's interested. If you launch TeXworks from Terminal, that may work around the problem I described.

Comment: I've described a potential workaround here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/208181/why-did-my-tex-related-gui-program-stop-working-in-mac-os-x-yosemite

Comment: It works!!! good god!!! Was frustrating. Anyways if you add it as an answer I will accept it. Thank you so much.

Comment: why is it looking at `/opt/local/var/db/texmf/fonts/...`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Launching TeXworks in the Terminal will work around an environment variable bug in OS X Yosemite. Assuming you have TeXworks installed in the /Applications folder, your command in Terminal would look like this:

```
/Applications/TeXworks.app/Contents/MacOS/TeXworks
```

Press return after entering the command, and TeXworks should launch. Correct functioning will depend on the caveats listed [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/208182/61839) in the more detailed description of the problem.

Answer (score 5):

I ran this command, which re-instated the epstopdf binary:

```
sudo tlmgr  install epstopdf
```

Answer (score 0):

I am a casual user, I found the same problem using Texstudio in Yosemite, it bugged me for so long, and I fixed it!

here is what you do: (based on this old post: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/829749/launch-mac-eclipse-with-environment-variables-set)

Create an empty text file called "texstudio.sh" in the Texstudio application bundle directory

```
/Applications/Texstudio.app/Contents/MacOS.
```

Open the texstudio.sh in a text editor an enter the following contents:

```
#!/bin/sh

export PATH=$PATH:/usr/texbin

logger "`dirname \"$0\"`/eclipse"

exec "`dirname \"$0\"`/eclipse" $@
```

In the Terminal set the executable flag of the shell script texstudio.sh, i.e.:

```
chmod +x /Applications/Texstudio.app/Contents/MacOS/texstudio.sh
```

Open the Texstudio.app Info.plist and change the value for the key Executable from texstudio to texstudio.sh.

MacOS X does not automatically detect that the Texstudio.app's Info.plist has changed. Therefore you need to force update the LaunchService database in the Terminal by using the lsregister command:
    `/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Support/lsregister -v -f /Applications/Texstudio.app`

The next time you launch Texstudio.app from the Dock or from the Finder the environment variables should be set

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem with texstudio and yosemite.

I fixed it like this.
open ~/.bash_profile in a text editor

add the line

`export PATH=$PATH:/usr/texbin`

save the file.