# How to Use Arara in TexStudio

Tags: texstudio, arara, latexindent

I'm trying to use latexindent to clean up my code in TexStudio and I can't get it to work.

- I've installed latexindent and arara in Tex Live Utility
- I've added a User Command to TexStudio of: `/usr/texbin/arara -v -l %`
- At the top of my document I've written: `% arara: indent: {overwrite: yes, trace: yes}`

When I run the user command, I get:

```
/usr/texbin/arara: line 2: kpsewhich: command not found
Error: Unable to access jarfile
```

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: Do you have `arara.jar` in the system path? What do you get if you type `arara.jar -v` in the terminal?

Comment: I get -bash: arara.jar: command not found

Comment: Then add `arara.jar` in system path. Don't ask me how, I am on windows ;)

Comment: Did you install the full texlive? If so, how did you install it? Did you use apt-get? If you use the method illustrated in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1092/how-to-install-vanilla-texlive-on-debian-or-Ubuntu then arara and latexindent should work pretty much out of box -- let us know, and hopefully we can help :)

Answer (score 3):

If you use Yosemite, the error is repeatable. Joseph Wright has found a temporary solution until the issue will be fixed by the maintainers:

> Start TeXWorks from the terminal

```
/Applications/TeXworks.app/Contents/MacOS/TeXworks &
```

http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/19316883#19316883

and see:

[texworks on mac epstopdf or repstopdf not found](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/208059/texworks-on-mac-epstopdf-or-repstopdf-not-found/208310#208310)

Comment: To this end, you may be able to edit /etc/paths to modify your global PATH to include texbin. This may allow the user to open the application normally. I'm not sure about the path to that file -- I'm not in front of my computer right now :)

Comment: @SeanAllred: Thanks for the hint. I tried it, unfortunately without any success. Maybe I missed something and you can improve the answer (it's a cw)

Comment: Don't launch it using `open`, as you'll end up with the same bad environment. Launch the executable inside the .app bundle directly, as described here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/208310/61839

Answer (score 0):

Same problem as the OP on Yosemite 10.10.3. My *simple* solution was to create an app (so that I could launch it from Alfred) in Automator:

```
on run {input, parameters}
    tell application "texstudio"
        activate
    end tell
    return input
end run
```